# Using OR in type interface typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array in which every index item can be either `IBusinessDetailCompetitor` or `ICustomerCompetitorInstant`

So can I do something ilke this
 `customerCompititorArray: (IBusinessDetailCompetitor[] | ICustomerCompetitorInstant[])`

But this is giving errror. Please help.

Comment: @yudhiesh :/ i don't think so

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

The item in array should be [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types):

```
interface IBusinessDetailCompetitor {
    a: string
}
interface ICustomerCompetitorInstant {
    b: string
}

const customerCompititorArrayCorrect: Array<IBusinessDetailCompetitor | ICustomerCompetitorInstant> = [{a: '1'}, {b: '2'}]
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=123&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICECuBnUFvYAiEYcwANgMID2AtgA4nBjVTIDeAUMj8nAFzJsYKKADmnAL6dQkWIhSpKOFrWg0GTFlFQhhccB268ARoOGiQE6ZwTU9YZAhV11des2asAglChwATxo-CAQwQV9-AIAeDBw8AmJSCg1GMC82AB80ZWFXKFStVl19cAA+ZABeZABtdgFkAHIARkbJABoOMyaAJjaAXU5be2EnFzUC909tSMDBAAo43BB8IhIyKnciqBr+5GylcbdNdO0S0nBdgEoq2vrBFrbO9m7Gvsl+oA)

Comment: This also allows an object of `{a: "", b: ""}` to be in the array. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICECuBnUFvYAiEYcwANgMID2AtgA4nBjVTIDeAUMj8nAFzJsYKKADmnAL6dQkWIhSpKOFrWg0GTFlFQhhccB268ARoOGiQE6ZwTU9YZAhV11des2asAglChwATxo-CAQwQV9-AIAeDBw8AmJSCg1GMC82AB80ZWFXKFStVl19cAA+ZABeZABtdgFkAHIARkaAGmQzJoAmRskO9i7G3skAXU5be2EnFzUC909tSMDBAAo43BB8IhIyKnciqBrR5GylWbdNdO0S0nBjgEoq2vrBFr6BoZHRoA